# IE 7 Group Policy Settings Help

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to modify Internet Explorer 7 settings to support a internally located, web-based tool and need to do this via GPO.  The tool requires that "always allow session cookies" and "check for newer versions of stored pages" both be set.
I'm wondering if anyone can assist me in locating where I find the options to set these in a GPO.
If this cannot be done via GPO is that an alternative way someone can suggest that doesn't involve visiting each workstation to manually set the options?  Any assistance is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For odd things like this, I have used [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to track down exactly which registry settings are being applied.  From there you can push the registry settings out via a login script or create a custom administrative template for group policy.